# C++ Error: no match for call to '(Vector3 (double, double, double)'

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

So i'm having this error that prevents me from continuing my assignment.
Here is the code:

```
#include "std_lib_facilities.h"

class Vector3
{
public:
    Vector3();
    Vector3(double x1);
    Vector3(double x1, double y1);
    Vector3(double x1, double y1, double z1);

//Helper functions
    double x() {return x1;}
    double y() {return y1;}
    double z() {return z1;}


private:
    double x1,y1,z1;
};

/** Constructor Definitions **/
Vector3::Vector3(double x, double y, double z){
    x1=x;
    y1=y;
    z1=z;
}
Vector3::Vector3(double x, double y){
    x1=x;
    y1=y;
}
Vector3::Vector3(double x){
    x1=x;
}
Vector3::Vector3()
{
    x1=0;
    y1=0;
    z1=0;
}

/** Operator Overloading **/

ostream& operator<<(ostream&os, Vector3& v) //<< Overloading
 {
    return os <<"["<<v.x()
              <<", "<<v.y()
              <<", "<<v.z()
              <<"]"<<endl;
}

Vector3 operator+(Vector3 v1, Vector3 v2) //+ Overloading
{
    double a,b,c;
    Vector3 vector1(a,b,c);
    return vector1( v1.x()+v2.x() , v1.y()+v2.y() , v1.z()+v2.z() );
}
```

This is a header file. The error happens at the //+Overloading ( last bit of code) at the return line.
I googled it but with no avail. Mostly people are suggesting that i'm using a function or a variable that has the same name with something else but I can't find something like that.

Comment: @zenith well yes its right at the top, in the class Vector3

Comment: Now see, I don't believe you posted the correct compiler error. It would at least mention `operator()`.

Answer (score 2):

```
Vector3 vector1(a,b,c);    
return vector1( v1.x()+v2.x() , v1.y()+v2.y() , v1.z()+v2.z() );
```

First you're constructing a `Vector3` object using uninitialized variables. Then you're trying to invoke the call operator (`operator()`) on that object. Your `operator+` function should probably look something like this:

```
Vector3 operator+(Vector3 v1, Vector3 v2) //+ Overloading
{
    return Vector3( v1.x()+v2.x() , v1.y()+v2.y() , v1.z()+v2.z() );
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! But I still don't understand what you meant and why it doesn't work. Can you explain if you have the time?

Comment: @AkisKiraleos It's the same as writing: `int i; return i(1);` What would you expect that to do?

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is on this line:

`return vector1( v1.x()+v2.x() , v1.y()+v2.y() , v1.z()+v2.z() );`

What do you think the expression is going to do?  It looks like you're treating the `vector1` variable as a function name. Is that what you meant to do?

If you are trying to construct a new object of type `Vector3`, then you'll probably need to use the typename `Vector3` at some point.

Comment: Well now I have another problem if I do that. When I try to cout the sum of 2 Vector2 I can't. Because the +overload doesn't return a Vector3 object so the <<overload doesn't work with it. For example:  
    cout<<vector1+vector2
doesn't work, while
    vector1+vector2 works by itself

Comment: If you do what? What did you do? Did you do this: `return Vector3( v1.x()+v2.x() , v1.y()+v2.y() , v1.z()+v2.z() );`?